# Batch Read inside flatMapGroupWithState

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've been looking for a way to perform an update to a streaming application's state based on the data already present in this state. The application determines if there is missing data via the processing done inside the *flatMapGroupWithState* function and should perform a read to fetch this missing data.

Is it possible to perform such an operation?

The *flatMapGroupWithState* is computed on the executor so the *SparkSession* isn't available. Trying to use *SparkSession.getActiveSession* or when trying to create a new *SparkSession* results in the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active or default Spark session found
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.$anonfun$active$2(SparkSession.scala:1055)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.$anonfun$active$1(SparkSession.scala:1055)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.active(SparkSession.scala:1054)
at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.getTable(DeltaDataSource.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
```